# How to "negate" value: if true return false, if false return true?

Tags: python, boolean, negate

```
if myval == 0:
   nyval=1
if myval == 1:
   nyval=0
```

Is there a better way to do a toggle in python, like a  nyvalue = not myval ?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use the [`not` boolean operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
nyval = not myval
```

`not` returns a *boolean* value (`True` or `False`):

```
>>> not 1
False
>>> not 0
True
```

If you must have an integer, cast it back:

```
nyval = int(not myval)
```

However, the python `bool` type is a subclass of `int`, so this may not be needed:

```
>>> int(not 0)
1
>>> int(not 1)
0
>>> not 0 == 1
True
>>> not 1 == 0
True
```

Answer (score 3):

In python, [`not`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) is a boolean operator which gets the opposite of a value:

```
>>> myval = 0
>>> nyvalue = not myval
>>> nyvalue
True
>>> myval = 1
>>> nyvalue = not myval
>>> nyvalue
False
```

And `True == 1` and `False == 0` (if you need to convert it to an integer, you can use `int()`)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`not`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html), for example:

```
return not myval
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = not (False | variable)
```

is similar to

```
if variable == True:
    variable = False
elif variable == False:
    variable = True
```