# Python - ways of checking True/False without ==?

Tags: python, boolean

I've defined my code to ensure all letters inside a loop are indeed letters with

```
if letter.isalpha() != True:
    return 'Failed'
```

This works. However, for what I'm doing we are strictly instructed to not compare `Boolean` values to `True`/`False` using `==`, and with the way I'm doing it it's basically the same thing. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Negation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168046/python-how-to-negate-value-if-true-return-false-if-false-return-true

Comment: are those letters coming from a word?

Comment: @Padraic yes they are. The actual function I'm doing this in is significantly more complex and this irons out most of the irrelevant words.

Comment: @Alex K is the actual term for this sort of thing referred to as negation?

Comment: You know you can simply call it on the word yes? `"foo".isalpha() -> True` `"foo!".isalpha() -> False`

Comment: Oh, I wasn't thinking. I typed that in after a few tests failed and this was one of the reasons as to why. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Just for reference, using `==` and `!=` with `True` is strongly discouraged by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  The same goes for `False`.  You should always use `if value:` or `if not value:` instead.

Comment: @iCodez Yeah cheers. I was wondering why my university coding guide told me to not use it which lead me to asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
if not letter.isalpha():
    return 'Failed'
```

Comment: @MoisheLipsker That is for C based languages.

Answer (score 0):

isalpha() method returns boolean value, so you don't need to compare with != True. So you can just use **not** negation.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rafael said, `letter.isalpha()` returns a boolean. You can negate it using `not`.

(edit) Answer:

```
if not letter.isalpha():
    return 'Failed'
```

Comment: why are you adding the exact same answer?

Comment: The top answer was edited after I added mine. The edit added a not to the code.